# Pandas DataFrame: concat instead of append

Tags: python, pandas

After a Pandas-update, I get a bunch of warnings for append to be depecated. This is the code to analyze a gpx file:

```
import pandas    as bib_pandas
gpx = mod_gpxpy.parse(open(dir_file))   # read GPX-File
gpx_points = gpx.tracks[0].segments[0].points
data_frame = bib_pandas.DataFrame(columns=["lon", "lat", "elev", "time"])
for point in gpx_points:
    # data_frame = data_frame.append({"lon": point.longitude, "lat": point.latitude, "elev": point.elevation, "time": point.time}, ignore_index=True) # OLD code, works, with warning!
    bib_pandas.concat([data_frame, {"lon": point.longitude, "lat": point.latitude, "elev": point.elevation, "time": point.time}], ignore_index=True)  # NEW Code, ERROR
```

As shown above, I tried to use concat instead of append, but this gives an error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

With my old code, thedataframe looks like this:

```
           lon        lat   elev                      time
0    14.936605  55.498336  421.0 2020-08-20 07:15:39+00:00
..         ...        ...    ...                       ...
416  13.936569  55.498304  421.0 2020-08-20 08:12:16+00:00
[417 rows x 4 columns]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need neither `append` nor `concat`, you can use:

```
l = [{"lon": point.longitude, "lat": point.latitude,
      "elev": point.elevation, "time": point.time}
     for point in gpx_points]

data_frame = bib_pandas.DataFrame(l)
```

Comment: Thank you. looks fine for a test-file. BUT you missed the `, ignore_index=True`. How can I bring it back?

Comment: You shouldn't need this, the index should already be a range (0 -> n), no?

Comment: May be you're right. The original [author of the code](https://thatmaceguy.github.io/python/gps-data-analysis-intro/) (search within the page `ígnore_index`) used it, so I'd feel better to have it back ...